# Nested object keys type to mapped union

Tags: typescript, react-navigation, union-types, mapped-types, nested-types

I want to create a type `NestedKeys` that iterates over the given nested type `RootNav` and collects all keys where the value is `Nested<T>` and make this a union type of strings containing the keys, while following the nested structure (maybe recursive?)

```js
type Nav = {
  [key: string]: NestedNav<Nav> | object | undefined
}

type NestedNav<T extends Nav> = T

type RootNav = {
  LoginNav: NestedNav<LoginNav>;
  RegistrationNav: NestedNav<RegistrationNav>;
  AppNav: NestedNav<AppNav>
}

type AppNav = {
  MainNav: NestedNav<MainNav>;
  FooScreen: undefined
  BarScreen: {id: string}
};

type LoginNav = {
  LoginScreen: undefined
}

type RegistrationNav = {
  RegistrationScreen: undefined
}

type MainNav = {
  HomeScreen: undefined
  ProfileScreen: undefined
}
```

The endresult should be

```js
type NestedKeys<RootNav>
// → "RootNav" | "LoginNav" | "RegistrationNav" | "AppNav" | "MainNav"
```

I had something in mind like this, but don't know how to do it properly. This doesn't work:

````
type NestedKeys<T extends Nav> = T[keyof T] extends NestedNav<any> ? NestedKeys<T[keyof T]> : T```
````

Comment: please provide reproducible example: `NestedNav`

Comment: I don't think it is of any importance how it looks like. It can be just an object. I think you need to adress it with an conditional type (extends) to make the difference between something else.

Comment: @captain-yossarian updated the answer, maybe it is now clearer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do but it requires a small refactor of types.
TypeScript does not support `macros`. There is no concept of `value.toString` like in javascript. It means that having some type you are unable to get string representation of type name.

That's why I have added `tag` property:

```js
type Prefix = `${string}Nav`

type Nav =
    & Record<'tag', Prefix>
    & {
        [key: Prefix]: undefined | Nav
    }

type NestedNav<T extends Nav> = T

type RootNav = {
    tag: 'RootNav'
    LoginNav: NestedNav<LoginNav>;
    RegistrationNav: NestedNav<RegistrationNav>;
    AppNav: NestedNav<AppNav>
}
type AppNav = {
    tag: 'AppNav'
    MainNav: NestedNav<MainNav>;
    FooScreen: undefined
    BarScreen: { id: string }
};

type LoginNav = {
    tag: 'LoginNav';
    LoginScreen: undefined
}

type RegistrationNav = {
    tag: 'RegistrationNav';
    RegistrationScreen: undefined
}

type MainNav = {
    tag: 'MainNav';
    HomeScreen: undefined
    ProfileScreen: undefined
}

type DefaultTag<T> = T extends { tag: infer Tag } ? Tag : never

type GetNames<T, Cache extends any[] = [DefaultTag<T>]> =
    (T extends string
        ? Cache[number]
        : {
            [Prop in keyof T]:
            (T[Prop] extends { tag: infer Tag }
                ? GetNames<T[Prop], [...Cache, Tag]>
                : GetNames<T[Prop], Cache>)
        }[keyof T]
    )

type Result = GetNames<RootNav>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThAZgSwB5QLxQAYBIDeAzsHMgHYDmAvgHICGAbtgFDOiRT0ObNR9QAyKACUIAYwD2cACYAeAOTA6FeQBpYCFKgB8vfkPx7+-ANoBrCCABcGpGgC6NgK5lpdshGlQAPp0ZGoKlZ2aBoIYk8uWQAVKAhUYAhXQj8GbUwoaODwaGEJCWAuDMNjJQobeTyCrnkAgBkJCnIuGzCI6SiGprIubQBuANEm4jg6YGQJHsZW8MSOxlkh5BGxiam0geMAQTAwFs5ZyIWdvcZdIJCoE6KsEv4yiuvGWuMAWTpm6YP2qPfPjYCADF8gBlMQIJLOVzuTwBABCdDgYIhZBs+CgyGkNhG5AogWYVAGbByUC6-2KAQeUHkZPW8k2-FpyIgkKgLjcKA80gJ2Q4SxW40mNygdz4VMqEGGJFWQueDL4-OlgrIzNZ7Jh3KCxI4f3WFNKygqupq8qgAAkJABbCCq1Fs6Gc2HGeASFAAGxt4JZdvVjs1vOgABEkHQnG7gNFlDF0lhYvFEskRVAqeREBA4JllIEoAB+TN4mweBjpgNQADiEEKdGthBi6gAwnQxAALaDxpLSFJ0MggEz2DImYOIUPhyMUaP2GMBAAUcYSHZSOMoAWMecbLYgJjITktACN0-YV-w0UfjHwTC6wBiyFALCBXZlHKez7OL3AJGB++3E+iU2Q0xmY74meIFnnmFZVjWMRvh+9jqCYAB0SHrq26hjpOz6gVANgQfQUHRDBn4Nk2rbaAAlM+VDmJYD7RIexgUdquThGGwAZLh1bhIs+RVmkQA)

type `Prefix` represents any nav name.

type `Nav` represents valid nav type.

type `GetNames` iterates recursively through `nav` type and adds `tag` property to `Cache` if such exists.